# How can I practice searching and replacing with regular expressions interactively in Emacs?

Tags: regular-expressions, learning

Searching and replacing using regular expressions is clearly a powerful tool to the Emacs user who can routinely perform these actions. However, as an Emacs (and/or programming) beginner, regular expressions need to be learned and practiced.

Can I learn and train regular expressions *interactively* in Emacs, similarly to the built-in Emacs tutorial? If not, what are other suggestions to utilize Emacs to practice the use of regular expressions for searching and replacing?

Comment: This documentation is kinda complete: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Regexp

Answer (score 18):

Besides `regexp-builder` you might also consider [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el) to provide you with visual feedback on the replace in progress:

[image: visual-regexp snapshot]

Comment: Or even `anzu`, which does the same and more.

Comment: `anzu` doesn't seem comparable at all.

Answer (score 17):

You can try `M-x regexp-builder RET` which is an interactive regular expression matcher, that's not bad

Comment: Don't panic when `C-g` doesn't exit like you expect. `C-c C-q` is the default keybinding to quit regexp builder when you are done practicing.

Answer (score 6):

I use `regexp-builder` which let's you test regexps interactively and get feedback.
And of course, once I started using that, I immediately asked myself "How do I feed this regexp into `query-replace-regexp`?"

The answer I chose is the following function defined on the [EmacsWiki ReBuilder](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReBuilder) page.

```
(defun reb-query-replace (to-string)
  "Replace current RE from point with `query-replace-regexp'."
  (interactive
   (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
          (list (query-replace-read-to (reb-target-binding reb-regexp)
                                       "Query replace"  t))))
  (with-current-buffer reb-target-buffer
    (query-replace-regexp (reb-target-binding reb-regexp) to-string)))
```

So my workflow is:

1. `M-x re-builder`
2. *type type type*
3. `M-x reb-query-replace`

Answer (score 3):

It can be a tremendous help when learning to use regexps to see what is matched by which parts of a regexp - in particular, regexp groups.  And to do that interactively and incrementally.

Along the lines of @immerr's answer, [**Icicles** search](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) has had similar [highlighting](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchHighlightingContextLevels) for a long time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [helm-regexp](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-18) that displays regex groups separately.

Answer (score 1):

Not within emacs, but http://rubular.com/ is basically `regexp-builder` with a cheat-sheet. You can set up an example and have it spit out a [link](http://rubular.com/r/iUJsL6xsyr) to that example. I use this when discussing regex with a team.

Comment: Does Ruby use emacs-flavored Regexp?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Dave F's `regexp-builder` you can also create arbitrary text to practice pattern matching against.

The most useful feature of this command is that it will highlight matches in the buffer as the pattern is created to assist you in ensuring the proper pattern matches.

Using `(query-replace-regexp)` (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>) and creating a regular expression to perform the replacement you want will help you practice.

Comment: What benefit does this offer to someone wanting to "practice" regular expressions that `regexp-builder` does not already offer?  The problem with `query-replace-regexp` is that you need to write an entire regexp and then commit to it to find out what it matches.  If you don't like the result you have to start all over again.  `regexp-builder` shows matches on the fly which makes it easier to tweak your regexp until it works if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I admit that's the downside of it.  However if you're familiar with regular expressions using `query-replace-regexp` will get you used to using it in Emacs specifically

Comment: Perhaps... but it doesn't seem to match what the OP is asking for.  "If you're familiar with regular expressions," then you don't really have a need to *learn* regular expressions at all.

Comment: OP is asking how to learn how/when to use them *interactively* as an Emacs beginner.  They might already have some regexp knowledge from other types of regexp.