# Extending org-mode with more markups

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, org-emphasis

I want to add a markup and formatting for such markup, i.e. `<kbd>...</kbd>` with a box surrounds such markup. I also want the mark up to be compatible with `(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)`. That is, when the variable is set to `t`, the `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`tags should disappear, leaving the text between it with the specified formatting above.

The answer posted in this question: [How to highlight text permanently in org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-in-org-mode) **does not** solve this problem, since it is only applicable for existing markups, not extending Org with new markups.

Comment: http://endlessparentheses.com/inserting-the-kbd-tag-in-org-mode.html

Comment: @kaushalmodi I asked how to add a mark up that when Org sees it, it adds text properties accordingly and in a way such that the markup can be hidden with `org-hide-emphasis-markers`, not how to quickly insert a `kbd` tag.

Comment: I agree. I put this as a comment as it was related to kbd tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to highlight text permanently in org-mode](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-in-org-mode)

Comment: @erikstokes that solution is only applicable for existing markups, not new ones.

Comment: starting points with this question: [Color-code a new generic character combination](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/color-code-a-new-generic-character-combination)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have done something [similar](http://fredtantini.free.fr/blog/index.php?article13/un-peu-de-typographie-et-marquer-les-raccorcus-clavier-dans-org-mode).
It's in French, but the code should speak for itself. I use `‰` for
the marker (I use a [bepo](http://bepo.fr) layout), and when I do, the
marked text as a pressed-button style.

I am not fluent in lisp, so there may be room for improvement.

What I have done is that, when using `‰` for marker, the marked text has a pressed-button style, and when exported it is translated to `<kbd>`

First, I had to define a new face:

```lisp
(defface my-face-org-keystroke
  '((t (:inherit shadow 
        :box (:line-width -2 ;neg. in order to keep the same size of lines
              :color "grey75"
              :style pressed-button)))) "Face for keystrokes"
        :group 'org-faces)
```

Then customize  `org-emphasis-alist` :

```lisp
(("*" bold)
 ("/" italic)
 ("_" underline)
 ("=" org-code verbatim)
 ("~" org-verbatim verbatim)
 ("+"
  (:strike-through t))
 ("‰" my-face-org-keystroke verbatim));This line is what you want to add
```

For the export, you may need to load `ox.el` with `(require 'ox)`.

Then each time `bold` or `code` appears in a function (in `ox-org.el`), I have created a similar function (or modified existing ones):

```lisp
;creation
(defun org-html-keystroke (keystroke contents info)
  "Transcode KEYSTROKE from Org to HTML.
CONTENTS is nil.  INFO is a plist holding contextual
information."
  (format (or (cdr (assq 'my-object-keystroke org-html-text-markup-alist)) "%s")
          (org-html-encode-plain-text (org-element-property :value keystroke))))


;creation
(defun org-element-my-object-keystroke-parser ()
  "Parse code object at point.

Return a list whose CAR is `my-object-keystroke' and CDR is a plist with
`:value', `:begin', `:end' and `:post-blank' keywords.

Assume point is at the first tilde marker."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (unless (bolp) (backward-char 1))
    (looking-at org-emph-re)
    (let ((begin (match-beginning 2))
          (value (org-match-string-no-properties 4))
          (post-blank (progn (goto-char (match-end 2))
                             (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
          (end (point)))
      (list 'my-object-keystroke
            (list :value value
                  :begin begin
                  :end end
                  :post-blank post-blank)))))

;creation
(defun org-element-my-object-keystroke-interpreter (keystroke contents)
  "Interpret KEYSTROKE object as Org syntax.
CONTENTS is nil."
  (format "‰%s‰" (org-element-property :value keystroke)))


;modification
(defconst org-element-object-successor-alist
  '((subscript . sub/superscript) (superscript . sub/superscript)
    (bold . text-markup) (code . text-markup) (italic . text-markup)
    (strike-through . text-markup) (underline . text-markup)
    (verbatim . text-markup) (entity . latex-or-entity)
    (latex-fragment . latex-or-entity) (my-object-keystroke . text-markup))
  "Alist of translations between object type and successor name.
Sharing the same successor comes handy when, for example, the
regexp matching one object can also match the other object.")

;modification
(defconst org-element-all-objects
  '(bold code entity export-snippet footnote-reference inline-babel-call
         inline-src-block italic line-break latex-fragment link macro
         radio-target statistics-cookie strike-through subscript superscript
         table-cell target timestamp underline verbatim my-object-keystroke)
  "Complete list of object types.")


;modification
(defun org-element-text-markup-successor ()
  "Search for the next text-markup object.

Return value is a cons cell whose CAR is a symbol among `bold',
`italic', `underline', `strike-through', `code' and `verbatim'
and CDR is beginning position."
  (save-excursion
    (unless (bolp) (backward-char))
    (when (re-search-forward org-emph-re nil t)
      (let ((marker (match-string 3)))
        (cons (cond
               ((equal marker "*") 'bold)
               ((equal marker "/") 'italic)
               ((equal marker "_") 'underline)
               ((equal marker "+") 'strike-through)
               ((equal marker "~") 'code)
               ((equal marker "=") 'verbatim)
               ((equal marker "‰") 'my-object-keystroke) 
               (t (error "Unknown marker at %d" (match-beginning 3))))
              (match-beginning 2))))))
```

Next, I have defined a `my-html` backend for the export:

```lisp
(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-html 'html
  :translate-alist '((my-object-keystroke . org-html-keystroke))
  :menu-entry ' (?h 1
                    ((?r "my-html"  org-html-export-to-my-html))))

(defun org-html-export-to-my-html
  (&optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
  "Export current buffer to a HTML file.

Return output file's name."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((extension (concat "." org-html-extension))
         (file (org-export-output-file-name extension subtreep))
         (org-export-coding-system org-html-coding-system))
    (org-export-to-file 'my-html file
      async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)))


(defun org-html-publish-to-my-html (plist filename pub-dir)
  "Publish an org file to my-html.
Return output file name."
  (org-publish-org-to 'my-html filename
                      (concat "." (or (plist-get plist :html-extension)
                                      org-html-extension "html"))
                      plist pub-dir))

(defun org-html-convert-region-to-my-html ()
  "Assume the current region has org-mode syntax, and convert it to HTML.
This can be used in any buffer.  For example, you can write an
itemized list in org-mode syntax in an HTML buffer and use this
command to convert it."
  (interactive)
  (org-export-replace-region-by 'my-html))
```

So when I use `C-c C-e h r` it's exported correctly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As suggested by OP in comments, you may need to use `org-mode-restart` (or `org-reload`) or kill/reload your buffer.

---

**Edit:** This works for org-mode with versions prior 8.3 (that is till 8.2.10)

With versions ≥8.3.1, I have to modify

- org-element-all-objects
- possibly org-element-object-restrictions
- org-element--set-regexps
- org-element--object-lex

and of course still add the functions

- org-element-my-object-keystroke-parser
- org-element-my-object-keystroke-interpreter

but

- org-element-object-successor-alist
- org-element-text-markup-successor

are now deleted.

Thanks to [Charles C. Berry](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/106232) for his help.

Comment: Is `%` marker a built-in one? I cannot get it to work with latest Org. As for other markers, it works fine if I change their faces. But is there a way to really add our own markers? Nevertheless, your answer is useful.

Comment: `%` is not currently used as a marker. You can use it the same way I used `‰`. I don't understand your second question though, `‰` **is** a new marker.

Comment: Ok, I was able to make the `%` marker work, but I had to run `org-reload`. You should update the answer with that command.

Comment: Actually, we don't need `org-reload` but `org-mode-restart`. The thing is, we must kill previous Org buffer and create a new one for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have updated my answer. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`org-extra-emphasis`**: *Extra Emphasis markers for Emacs Org mode*](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-extra-emphasis).

The solution outlined here works with `org-9.5.3`.

To get this

### Buffer *as it is*

[image: Buffer when org-extra-emphasis-mode is OFF]

### Buffer as it is rendered in Emacs with `org-extra-emphasis-mode`

[image: Buffer as is rendered when org-extra-emphasis-mode is ON]

### Buffer as it is rendered in Firefox when exporter to HTML

[image: HTML export of org-export-emphasis.org as seen in Firefox]

do this

1. `emacs -Q`
2. Download [`org-extra-emphasis.el`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjambunathan/org-extra-emphasis/main/org-extra-emphasis.el) to say `~/Downloads/`
3. `M-x load-file ~/Downloads/org-extra-emphasis.el`
4. `M-x customize-group org-extra-emphasis`.  Customize `org-extra-emphasis-alist` variable and `org-extra-emphasis-1` face as below.

   [image: Customize org-extra-emphasis]
5. Open a file `org-extra-emphasis.org` and fill it with following content.  (**Note**: *For some reason, the global value of `org-hide-emphasis-markers` was not getting inherited in the `org` buffer.  So, I had to force its value using **a file local variable***.)

```
#+TITLE: Additional Emphasis Markers to Org mode files

Start Emacs, open a file with <kbd>C-x C-f<kbd>, do some edits, and
save it with <kbd>C-x C-s<kbd>.  Once you are happy with the edits you
can close Emacs with <kbd>C-x C-c<kbd>.

# Local Variables:
# org-hide-emphasis-markers: t
# End:
```

6. Steps 4 & 5 are equivalent to

   ```lisp
   (custom-set-variables
    '(org-extra-emphasis-alist '(("<kbd>" org-extra-emphasis-1)))
    '(org-hide-emphasis-markers t))

   (custom-set-faces
    '(org-extra-emphasis-1
      ((t (:background "yellow"
           :box (:line-width
                 (2 . 2)
                 :color "red"
                 :style released-button))))))
   ```
7. Export the above file to HTML with `C-c C-e h o`.  You will get the output shown earlier.
8. Export the above file to ODT with `C-c C-e o O`.  *You won't get the box around the emphasis market, but you will get the background color carried over.*
9. Repeat the above steps with `M-x org-extra-emphasis-mode`, and investigate the difference.

*(Note `org-extra-emphasis-mode`, contrary to it's name is **not** a `mode` at all.  Its effect is **global**)*

**When using `org-extra-emphasis`, you cannot use *an arbitrary string* as a emphasis marker. If some *emphasis marker* doesn't work with some export backend change the marker  to something else.**

**For example, using "#' as an emphasis marker is a bad idea. There may be no `#` in your *body text*, but the HTML exporter may introduce attributes with `#`--think colors, or hrefs.  The filter function cannot distinguish between `#` you introduced as an *extra emphasis* and the `#` that the HTML exporter itself introduced. This means that the export filter will happily mark any stretch of HTML text enclosed within a `#` as a `span`, and  you will end up with *a broken  HTML*.**

---

Unlike, [the solution shared here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12822/31220), which extends the parser, `org-extra-emphasis` uses an *export filter*, specifically `org-export-filter-plain-text-functions`.  So, if something goes wrong, you--*an intermediate-level user*--can easily fix things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to add markers for new org-mode markup options.

[According to this 2012 post](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-08/msg00781.html) it looks like org-mode's "emphasis markers will be hard-coded".  Doing a quick search for `org-emph-re` in `org.el` doesn't reveal any code that would actually generate `org-emph-re` from `org-emphasis-alist`.  Based on that it looks like `org-emph-re` won't search for anything that you add to `org-emphasis-alist`.

This is consistent with my experience (I can redefine the existing emphasis markers, but couldn't get org-mode to recognize `|` or `&` or `H`).

I'm not an expert here, though, and would love to find out that I'm wrong :)

Comment: Simply editing `org-emphasis-alist` won't add a new marker. You have to *additionally* work with `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` too. [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/how-to-make-my-own-org-mode-text-emphasis-work-again/35632#35632) gives a working solution.

Comment: Hey, that works!  At least, that achieves the same effect! :)   When one uses the `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` then one doesn't need to change `org-emphasis-alist` at all, evidently (I added the `org-font-lock...` code but didn't change my `org-emphasis-alist` and now things are being formatted)