# Easiest way to render an overline in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, fonts, font-lock, unicode

Org mode has support for showing unicode in place of latex commands through `org-pretty-entities`. Org mode also has support for underlining through font locks that are activated through the `_` character. If everything fails then I can directly input unicode characters through the character viewer (on OSX).

However, I have never been able to get emacs to render overlines or characters with bars on top, e.g. ̅B , using any of the above three methods. Is there a way to show such characters in org-mode? Can font-lock automatically render code like \bar{B} as  ̅B ?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to the comment I made partial progress. By adding `("̅" (:overline t))` to `org-emphasis-alist` `barber` is rendered with a bar/overline when I enter <kbd>C-x 8 RET 0 3 0 5 RET</kbd>
<kbd>barber</kbd> 
<kbd>C-x 8 RET 0 3 0 5 RET</kbd> 
.

But what I'd really like is to just enter, <kbd>\bar{barber}</kbd> to toggle its overline attribute. Is this possible?

Comment: There is an [overline face attribute](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html), but you'd need to extend `org` with [more markups](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/extending-org-mode-with-more-markups) to get it to work.  [This answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12822/253) appears to offer a roadmap to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't read the update completely. It seems as though you might be able to get `\bar{` to start the fontification, but to get `}` to stop it might be harder.

As an alternative (if you would like latex support), you might be able to control the export to LaTeX to output `\bar{` and `}`.

---

**Old answer (just the formatting)**: You provided everything needed: just add the item

```
("!" (:overline t) verbatim))
```

to your `org-emphasis-alist`. This makes `!barber!` appear with overline.

Example from .emacs

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-emphasis-alist
   (quote
    (("*" bold)
     ("/" italic)
     ("_" underline)
     ("=" org-verbatim verbatim)
     ("~" org-code verbatim)
     ("+"
      (:strike-through t))
     ("!"
      (:overline t)
      verbatim)))))
```