# Can one define custom delimiters for inline formatting in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, formatting

The title says it quite straight, what I am looking for is the following:

```
while *this* is bold, `that` should appear in a custom format
```

**Edit:** This question is no duplicate of [that](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-in-org-mode) although the answer is hidden there [in a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-in-org-mode#comment8917_5892). As I think it is worth to be found, I repeat it here:

It is [impossible](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-02/msg00405.html) to use self-defined delimiter symbols.

Comment: [This](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/extending-org-mode-with-more-markups) related question may help.