# Custom faces in org 9.0

Tags: org-mode

I created a highlighter for `org-mode` which worked great (pre orgmode 9.0). But now my customizations are being ignored...

Here is the excerpt from my `init.el` file:

```lisp
    ;;; Create highlighter face
    (defface my-highlight-face
       '((t (:inherit org-default :foreground "#000000" :background "#ffffe7")))
       "Face for highlighting text")
    (defvar my-highlight1-face 'my-highlight1-face)

    ;; Add to list 
    (setq org-emphasis-alist `(("*" bold)
                                     ("/" italic)
                                     ("_" underline)
                                     ("=" org-verbatim verbatim)
                                     ("~" org-code verbatim)
                                     ("+" ,(if (featurep 'xemacs) 'org-table '(:strike-through t)))
                                     ("!" my-highlight1-face verbatim)))

    ;;; Reload org to make it stick
    (org-reload)
```

To check that this worked, I restart emacs and run `M-x customize-variable` > `org-emphasis-alist`. Scrolling down, I can see that `my-highlight1-face` has been added to the list:

[image: screenshot of org-emphasis-alist]

But opening a random `org` buffer and typing `!text to highlight!` does nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. Show the exact error message. 2. The `,(if...)` won't be evaluated because you've hidden it inside `quote` - use backquote instead.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. I updated my code to use backquote and I just ran `--debug-init`. The ccomplete error message is posted above.

Comment: @Drew I have updated my original post. Turns out the error I was getting had no relevance. Fixed this and also swapped in backquotes but this still doesn't work. Please see revised above. Thanks!

Comment: The marker in your lisp code is a sharp sign while in the custom buffer it is an exclamation mark. How does this go together? As a general rule: Don't mix customization via customization interface and setting up options via `setq`. This can cause all sorts of confusion (on the software side and on the human side).

Comment: I actually have 4 different highlight faces. For the sake of brevity I paired this down to 1 for stackexchange but failed to select the same face for the screenshot. All my changes were done via `setq`. I'll revise the code above to match the screenshot.

Comment: Okay, I found this thread where another user was having a similar issue adding to org-emphasis-alist https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35626/12695 But I don't understand why this doesn't work, when I am overriding org-emphasis-alist and my changes are appearing in Customize? I even tried patching org.el and no go...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in the end, [this post](https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/adding-keywords-in-emacs/) by Steven Pigeon, along with @Tobias' [earlier post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/how-to-make-my-own-org-mode-text-emphasis-work-again) gave me the way forward. Here is the revised code.

```lisp
    ;;; Create highlighter face for marking up text in org-mode
    (defface font-lock-highlight-face
       '((t (:inherit org-default :foreground "#000000" :background "#ffffe7")))
       "Face for highlighting text")
    (defvar font-lock-highlight-face 'font-lock-highlight-face)

    ;;; Add keywords
    (defun add-highlight-keywords()
      "adds custom keywords for highlighting text in org-mode."
      ;
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil
        '(("\\(!\\)\\([^[:space:]][^\n\r\t]+[^[:space:]]\\)\\(!\\)" . 'font-lock-highlight-face )))
    )
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'add-highlight-keywords)
```