# How can I exclude characters from being interpreted as emphasis-markers in Org-Mode?

Tags: org-emphasis

Is it possible to exclude the tilde `~` from being interpreted as emphasis-marker in Org-Mode in general?

Meaning not being escaped but being normal interpreted as simple Text?

[Emphasis-and-Monospace, Worg](https://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-Monospace.html)

Edit:

The following is now set in my `init.el` via `customize-variable`, but doesn't have any effect at all...

Of course, I restarted org-mode.
The target is to replace `~` with backtics for code-blocks.

```
'(org-emphasis-alist
  (quote
  (("*" bold)
   ("/" italic)
   ("_" underline)
   ("=" org-verbatim verbatim)
   ("`" org-code verbatim)
   ("+"
  (:strike-through t)))))
```

Comment: Markdown isn’t part of Emacs. Read the documentation for the markdown processor that you are using.

Comment: Details please: who interprets `~` as a markdown marker?

Comment: I really don't know... But Emacs treat them as 'org face' so there will be a possibility to configurate...  I would guess Emacs passed them to the used Org-Interpreter.

Comment: So you are talking about an Org mode file? `~` *is* interpreted in Org mode files (as a "verbatim" marker). In other modes however (i.e. generally), it is just a tilde: not interpreted at all. So it's not clear what you want to do: have the tilde not interpreted in Org mode files at all? Have you considered *not* using Org mode on the file? E.g. changing the major mode to `text-mode`?

Comment: Sorry - I meant in Org-Mode... I use the tilde for lines and can also use ```=``` as verbatim-marker. So it would be nice to exclude the tilde from being interpreter as marker.

Comment: EDIT:  ```~``` is for inline code and ```=``` for verbatim

Comment: EDIT: found it in documentation: ```org-emphasis-alist```, sorry RTFM...

Comment: Please note that org-emphasis-alist only affects how faces are used for displaying text in the buffer, it does not affect eg exports.

Comment: For export you also need to set `org-verbatim-re`. `org-set-emph-re` is supposed to do so when you set `org-emphasis-alist`, but it is buggy in that respect (at least in org-mode 9.3.7).

Comment: Trying and trying but no effect. Pls I edited the question, I don't know how I can get this to work...

Comment: Note, that you need to set the value of `org-emphasis-alist` with some customization command like `customize-option`.

Comment: [how-to-make-my-own-org-mode-text-emphasis-work-again](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/how-to-make-my-own-org-mode-text-emphasis-work-again) --- I think perhaps it won't work properly, so it might be better to let it be...

Comment: Edit: I used ```customize-option```, configured there, write to ```init.el``` and restarted Emacs. No success. If I reopen ```customize-option``` the changes are still present, but nevertheless they don't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

`org-emphasis-alist` wrongly suggests that you could change the emphasis markers.
No, that is not the case.
It rather gives you the possibility to change the faces for the emphasis markers rigidly [given by the syntax specification of org-mode](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Emphasis_Markers).

Nevertheless, the code below makes some functions of Org-Mode Version 9.2.3 somewhat more general, such that it accepts modifications of the emphasis markers. The modifications are marked by comments starting with `;; Tobias:`.

Note, that I used the unspecified third element of the entries of `org-emphasis-alist` to identify `verbatim` markers.

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(require 'org)

(defun org+-emphasis-chars ()
  "Return a list (EMPH VERB) of strings of markers.
EMPH is a string containing all marker chars
for non-verbatim emphasis.
VERB is a string containing all marker chars
for verbatim emphasis."
  (let (emph verb)
    (cl-loop for el in org-emphasis-alist
         if (eq (nth 2 el) 'verbatim)
         do (push (car el) verb)
         else
         do (push (car el) emph))
    (list
     (mapconcat #'identity emph "")
     (mapconcat #'identity verb ""))))

(defvar org+-emph-chars ""
  "String of characters working as emphasis markers.")

(defvar org+-verb-chars ""
  "String of characters working as verbatim markers.")

;; Modified version of `org-set-emph-re':
(defun org+-set-emph-re (var val)
  "Set variable and compute the emphasis regular expression."
  (set var val)
  (when (and (boundp 'org-emphasis-alist)
         (boundp 'org-emphasis-regexp-components)
         org-emphasis-alist org-emphasis-regexp-components)
    (pcase-let*
    ((`(,pre ,post ,border ,body ,nl) org-emphasis-regexp-components)
     (body (if (<= nl 0) body
         (format "%s*?\\(?:\n%s*?\\)\\{0,%d\\}" body body nl)))
     (template
      (format (concat "\\([%s]\\|^\\)" ;before markers
              "\\(\\([%%s]\\)\\([^%s]\\|[^%s]%s[^%s]\\)\\3\\)"
              "\\([%s]\\|$\\)") ;after markers
          pre border border body border post)))
      ;; Tobias: Added:
      (cl-multiple-value-setq (org+-emph-chars org+-verb-chars) (org+-emphasis-chars))
      (setq org-emph-re (format template org+-emph-chars)) ;; Tobias: Replaced literal "*+/_"
      (setq org-verbatim-re (format template org+-verb-chars))))) ;; Tobias: Replaced literal "~="

(advice-add 'org-set-emph-re :override #'org+-set-emph-re)

(org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-alist org-emphasis-alist)

;; Modified version of `org-do-emphasis-faces':
(defun org+-do-emphasis-faces (limit)
  "Run through the buffer and emphasize strings."
  (let ((quick-re (format "\\([%s]\\|^\\)\\([%s%s]\\)" ;; Tobias: modified format string
              (car org-emphasis-regexp-components)
              org+-emph-chars ;; Tobias: added
              org+-verb-chars))) ;; Tobias: added
    (catch :exit
      (while (re-search-forward quick-re limit t)
    (let* ((marker (match-string 2))
           (verbatim? (seq-contains org+-verb-chars (string-to-char marker)))) ;; Tobias: replaced (member ... '("=" "~"))
      (when (save-excursion
          (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
          (and
           ;; Do not match table hlines.
           (not (and (equal marker "+")
                 (org-match-line
                  "[ \t]*\\(|[-+]+|?\\|\\+[-+]+\\+\\)[ \t]*$")))
           ;; Do not match headline stars.  Do not consider
           ;; stars of a headline as closing marker for bold
           ;; markup either.
           (not (and (equal marker "*")
                 (save-excursion
                   (forward-char)
                   (skip-chars-backward "*")
                   (looking-at-p org-outline-regexp-bol))))
           ;; Match full emphasis markup regexp.
           (looking-at (if verbatim? org-verbatim-re org-emph-re))
           ;; Do not span over paragraph boundaries.
           (not (string-match-p org-element-paragraph-separate
                    (match-string 2)))
           ;; Do not span over cells in table rows.
           (not (and (save-match-data (org-match-line "[ \t]*|"))
                 (string-match-p "|" (match-string 4))))))
        (pcase-let ((`(,_ ,face ,_) (assoc marker org-emphasis-alist)))
          (font-lock-prepend-text-property
           (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2) 'face face)
          (when verbatim?
        (org-remove-flyspell-overlays-in
         (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
        (remove-text-properties (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2)
                    '(display t invisible t intangible t)))
          (add-text-properties (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2)
                   '(font-lock-multiline t org-emphasis t))
          (when org-hide-emphasis-markers
        (add-text-properties (match-end 4) (match-beginning 5)
                     '(invisible org-link))
        (add-text-properties (match-beginning 3) (match-end 3)
                     '(invisible org-link)))
          (throw :exit t))))))))

(advice-add 'org-do-emphasis-faces :override #'org+-do-emphasis-faces)
```